# React Native Custom Text Selection Menu

Tags: java, android, ios, swift, react-native

We are making a reading book application with React Native, but we have a problem about context menu. As you know many reading applications have a customized menu when user long press on text. There is a different menu instead of standart Android context menu (Copy-Paste-Select All)

For example: https://prnt.sc/w14pap (App XODO - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xodo.pdf.reader&hl=tr)
[image]

We want to show a menu like that.

We tried both in javascript side and react native plugin (https://github.com/Astrocoders/react-native-selectable-text), but we couldn't succeed.

Plugin supports only text, but we want to show icons only.

Could you help me please how can I make a context menu like this?

What we need?

- When user long press on text, a customized menu must be shown
- When user extend selection, the customized menu mustn't be lost or should be shown again.
- When user long press or extend selection, we must get start and end indexes of selection.
- We are using Text component because of we can colorize/underline some words of text. (TextInput doesn't support partial styling)

If it is not possible to do it without native bridge, is there any ready plugins in native side to bridge?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this in the end?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet. I think we must bridge to native. It is really so interesting that such a feature doesnt exist in react native :(

Comment: Yeah I couldn't find anything either. Looks like bridge is the only option right now